# Group by and merge to a JSON record in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I have rows in a table like this:

| ORG | Tenant | Dimension | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | MAU | 100 |
| A | T1 | WAU | 70 |
| B | T2 | MAU | 50 |
| B | T2 | Retention | 30 |

Now I need to group based on ORG, Tenant and remaining columns I need to convert into a single JSON as below.

| ORG | Tenant | CustomData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | {MAU:100,WAU:70} |
| B | T2 | {MAU:50,Retention:30} |

How can I achieve this in SQL Server or using C#? Do we have an out of the box support for this?

Thanks for your help,
Nikesh

Comment: Please tell us what you found when you did research into this.

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server (please update tags), to do it in SQL you need to start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieve with LINQ-to-SQL expression.

First group by `Org` and `Tenant`, for the grouping result part, the `CustomData` property is applied as Dictionary/KeyValuePair.

```cs
var result = dataList
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Org, x.Tenant },
            (key, g) => new 
            {
                Org = key.Org,
                Tenant = key.Tenant,
                CustomData = g.ToDictionary(y => y.Dimension, y => y.Count)
            })
    .ToList();
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rwTCuU)

> Output

```
[
  {
    "Org": "A",
    "Tenant": "T1",
    "CustomData": {
      "MAU": 100,
      "WAU": 70
    }
  },
  {
    "Org": "B",
    "Tenant": "T2",
    "CustomData": {
      "MAU": 50,
      "Retention": 30
    }
  }
]
```

**Note**:

As the `CustomData` is applied as Dictionary/KeyValuePair, the key **must be unique** before mapping. If in the input data there are the records with the **same `Org`, `Tenant`, and `Dimension`**, then you need to **group these 3 properties/columns and perform an aggregate sum first**.

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   ORG       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,Tenant    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,Dimension VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,Count1     INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test
(ORG,Tenant,Dimension,Count1) VALUES 
('A','T1','MAU',100),
('A','T1','WAU',70),
('B','T2','MAU',50),
('B','T2','Retention',30);
```

`For Json Path` change `Sql` tables into `Json` data, but you can get your desired result by using `String_agg` and `Concat`

```
select 
ORG,
Tenant,
concat('{',string_agg(concat(Dimension,':',Count1),','),'}' ) CustomData
from test
group by  ORG,Tenant
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f11f4365a16d5ccf417af406cf21c7a9)

Comment: For correct JSON you need `concat('{', string_agg(concat('"', string_escape(Dimension, 'json'),'":',Count1),','),'}' ) CustomData`

Answer (score 0):

Any specific solution is relative to your environment and it may not perform fast enough. However, You can use C# to reshape your list of records. Create a new JSON Object like so:

```
    {
  "MAU": [
    {
      "ORG": "A",
      "Tenant": "T1",
      "Dimension": "MAU",
      "Count": 100
    }
  ],
  "WAU" : [...]
}
```